# Show images very fast, picturebox/panel to slow

Tags: image, performance, replace

Okay the Title can be misleading.

But it´s like this.

I have made an application that constantly sends Images from Client A to Client B.
When Client B receives the image, it will replace the last image.

I currently use Picturebox or Panel, so pretty much:

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream((MemoryStream)NetSerializer.Serializer.Deserialize(tt1.GetStream()));
```

It looks weird though, but as you can se, it will just change the image, when it´s there.

This all goes well up to about 800x600, then it will bottleneck.

I don´t know the update frequency, but i am guessing it´s around 60fps, as i am taking screenshots from my desktop or particular windows.

The bandwidth is not the problem here as long as i don´t use .bmp at 800x600+ of course.

Anyway, my question is, what can i use to replace this way of showing images?

I am guessing something with Directx/OpenGL or something?

Sadly i haven´t found a way to even display an image with that, though then again, i have a hard time understanding it.

I am open for suggestions and examples.

EDIT:

I am thinking, maybe to use WPF to just show the image.
But i don´t know if i can change the background image from a winform, so if it´s possible then i am all ear.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into [Windows Imaging Components (WIC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654.aspx), on which raster graphics in WPF are based?

Comment: PS: WIC would perhaps only help with the encoding/decoding part. If you want to speed up image displaying, you might indeed have to resort to DirectX / XNA / OpenGL. Windows Forms is based on GDI+, which you'll probably want to avoid, since (AFAIK) it was designed for device-independent graphics, not so much for animation & video playback. WPF also is a framework mostly for vector graphics, but has a faster foundation; not sure if that would improve your situation.

Comment: Well is there a way to do it? Directx or OpenGL (or whatever), as i don´t get how to render, well, anything, i try looking at guides, but i have a problem where it says. Using.System.Directx.Direct3d, I don´t have Direct3d, even though i think i have the necessary SDKs.